# Raster Merging in R

Tags: r

I need a little help with some R syntax to complete what (I think) is a fairly straightforward task- hopefully someone can assist!

I have a raster map of the UK which is split into postcode areas (e.g. DE, NG, NR etc. 127 postcodes in total).

I have installed the package 'raster' and have successfully plotted the .img in R. All working and looks correct with the raster.

I also have a comma delimited CSV file containing the same postcodes as the raster with another column next to it containing revenue for each postcode.

**I was wondering if someone could help me merge/bind the revenue figures into the correct postcode in the raster so that I can plot revenue per postcode.**

I feel I should be using cbind and reclassify to do this but I can't work it out on my own

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

This is the code I have so far...not rocket science just yet.

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\[username]\\Documents\\GIS\\Test Data")
require(raster)
revenue<-read.table("revenue.csv",header=T,row.names=1,sep=",")
postcodes<-raster("C:\\Users\\[username]\\Documents\\GIS\\Test Data\\rasters\\postcodes\\postcodes.img")
trim(postcodes)
plot(postcodes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with the 'subs' method. You do not show us much about your data (e.g. head(revenue)), but it should work like this:

```
library(raster)
setwd("C:\\Users\\[username]\\Documents\\GIS\\Test Data")
postcodes <- raster("rasters\\postcodes\\postcodes.img")
revenue <- read.csv("revenue.csv")

subs(postcodes, revenue, by='code', which='rev')
```

where 'code' and 'rev' would be the column names in data.frame revenue that identify the postcode and revenue fields.

Comment: Robert, thanks very much for your answer. I will try this shortly and report back on whether it works. However, I understand the syntax and it looks to be exactly what I'm after. Thanks again for your time.